# Android: how to refer to EditText view

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, textview

I have the following layout:

```
<TextView 
    android:id = "@+id/HRNoninTextBox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/exitbtn" 
    android:text="Heart Rate"
    android:textSize = "20sp"/>
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/labelNoninHeartRate" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="00" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">                         
</EditText>
```

from the code i refer to these views, form my activity, in this way:

```
TextView tvHr= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HRNoninTextBox);

EditText etHr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.labelNoninHeartRate);
```

the first one does not produce any error, while the second statement produce the following error:

```
 01-09 13:24:57.599: W/dalvikvm(28816): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{aid.assistant233/aid.assistant233.AidAssistant233Activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at aid.assistant233.AidAssistant233Activity.onCreate(AidAssistant233Activity.java:331)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
01-09 13:24:57.619: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    ... 11 more
```

Where may be the problem?

Comment: As per LogCat you have `ClassCastException`which is can be redeemed by double checking that you are instantiating proper TextView or EditText to proper TextView or EditText. But you've already properly intialize EditText and TextView. So Try to `clean up your project`.

Comment: Your code is right ...clean your project and run..

Comment: your code is simply working fine..

Comment: Tahnks to all! I solved the problem cleaning and rebuild, as said by @NickL

Answer (score 0):

**Step1 :** you can clean/build your project as everyone said . but If you are not getting your issue solve by clean/build then check my step2 for it.

**Step:2:**
I am not Sure But Can you please check your xml file once again?

this also could be happen if You've  two elements with the same ID:

```
<TextView android:text="Hello Ahmedabad:" 
    android:id="@+id/txtahmedabad" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>

<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/txtahmedabad" 
    android:text="">
</EditText>
```

if this is so then Give them different IDs -
it could picking the first one (the `TextView`) which obviously can't be cast to an `EditText`.

Hope it will some how help you.